# Get closed form from a complicated closed-form generating function

Tags: taylor-expansion, generating-functions, closed-form

I have a closed form for a generating function:

$A(x)=\frac{x(x-1)(x+1)^3(x^3-x-1)}{(x^3+x^2-1)^2}$

The coefficient of $x^n$ in the above represents $a_n$ (the $n^{th}$ term of a sequence). I want a closed form for the sequence $a_n$. For example, the expansion done in:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2*(1%2Bx%2B(x%5E2*(x%2B1)%5E2)%2F(1-x%5E2-x%5E3))%2Bx*(1%2Bx%2B(x%5E2*(x%2B1)%5E2)%2F(1-x%5E2-x%5E3))*(x%5E2%2Bx%5E2*(1%2Bx%2B(x%5E2*(x%2B1)%5E2)%2F(1-x%5E2-x%5E3)))%2Bx%2B(x%5E2%2Bx%5E2*(1%2Bx%2B(x%5E2*(x%2B1)%5E2)%2F(1-x%5E2-x%5E3)))

shows the first few coefficients: $x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+8x^5+O(x^6)$. But I want a closed form for the general $n^{th}$ term $a_n$. What method should I use to get it?

Comment: I'm guessing the best you'll get for this is some horrible hypergeometric function "closed form"

Comment: perhaps you can get an asymptotic formula. Analytic combinatorics revolves around this. Have a look here: http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert $A(x)$ to partial fractions: if $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are the roots of $x^3+x^2-1$ (which is irreducible over the rationals):

$$ A(x) = {x}^{2}-2+\sum _{j=1}^3{\frac {-{r_j}^{2}+2\,r_j+2}{23\; \left( x-r_j \right) ^
{2}}}+\sum _{j=1}^3 \frac{-75\; r_j^2-370\; r_j + 78}{529\;(x-r_j)}
$$
and then use the Maclaurin series for $1/(x-r_j)$ and $1/(x-r_j)^2$.

Comment: I understand getting the roots of $x^3+x^2-1$. But how did you jump to this formulation of $A(x)$, from getting the roots? Did you use something like partial fractions decomposition? How did you notice the pattern of coefficients for the quadratic polynomial of roots?

Comment: As I said, it's partial fractions.  Actually I used Maple to get the coefficients, but it's not too hard to derive them by hand.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Though not a closed form we can use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* to derive an alternate explicit expression for $[x^n]A(x)$, the coefficient of $x^n$ of $A(x)$.

> At first we write $A(x)$ with increasing powers of the denominator $1-x^2-x^3$. We obtain using the *[Euclidian algorithm for polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Polynomials)*:
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x)&=\frac{x(x-1)(x+1)^3(x^3-x-1)}{(x^3+x^2-1)^2}\\
> &=\frac{x^8+2x^7-x^6-5x^5-3x^4+2x^3+3x^2+x}{(x^3+x^2-1)^2}\\
> &=\cdots\\
> &=x^2-2-\frac{x^2-x}{1-x^2-x^3}+\frac{x^2+x}{\left(1-x^2-x^3\right)^2}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Next we calculate the coefficient of $x^n$ of $\frac{1}{(1-x^2-x^3)^\alpha}$ which we need with $\alpha\in\{0,1\}$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]\frac{1}{\left(1-x^2-x^3\right)^{\alpha}}&=[x^n]\frac{1}{\left(1-x^2\left(1+x\right)\right)^{\alpha}}\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-\alpha}{j}(-1)^jx^{2j}(1+x)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{\alpha+j-1}{j}[x^{n-2j}](1+x)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{\alpha+j-1}{j}\binom{j}{n-2j}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the binomial series expansion of $(1+z)^{\alpha}$ with $z=-x^2(1+x)$.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^{2j}$ and set the upper bound of the series to $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ since the coefficient of $[x^{n-2j}]$ has to be non-negative.

> From (1) and (4) we obtain the coefficient of $A(x)$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^n]A(x)}&=[x^n]\left(x^2-2\right)-\left([x^{n-2}]-2[x^n]\right)\frac{1}{1-x^2-x^3}\\
> &\qquad+\left([x^{n-2}]+[x^n]\right)\frac{1}{\left(1-x^2-x^3\right)^2}\tag{5}\\
> &=[[n=2]]-2[[n=0]]-\left([x^{n-2}]-2[x^n]\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{j}{n-2j}x^j\\
> &\qquad+\left([x^{n-2}]-[x^{n-1}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}(j+1)\binom{j}{n-2j}x^j\tag{6}\\
> &\color{blue}{=[[n=2]]-2[[n=0]]+2\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{j}{n-2j}}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}(j+1)\binom{j}{n-1-2j}
> +\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}-1\right\rfloor}j\binom{j}{n-2-2j}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (6) we use the *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* $[[P]]$ which is $1$ if and only if the proposition $P$ is true and $0$ otherwise. We also use the representation of the coefficients from (2).
- In (7) we select the coefficients accordingly and collect corresponding terms.

> **Note:** The sequence $\left(\sum_{j}\binom{j}{n-2j}\right)_{n\geq 0}=(1,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,7,9,12,16,\ldots)$ is archived in OEIS as *[A000931](http://oeis.org/A000931)*.

Comment: Nice answer. I do wonder how "closed form" this is though, as it requires explicitly iterating over $O(n)$ entities (where $n$ is the size of the input) to compute. For this reason, I think I prefer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2567169/93666.

Comment: @user1145925: Thanks and I agree. Most of all I had in mind to show an alternate way of expanding the generating function. I've updated the text accordingly.